# Angular1: How to reflect ng-model errors on another element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I have a directive with the following template

```
<div>
    <span class="label">My Label</span>
    <input ng-model="name" required>
</div>
```

I want the label to be painted red when the input field is invalid.

How can I do that?

Currently I have another directive to sync all the errors from ngModelCtrl to the wrapping div

```
 <div add-all-errors>
   ... 
 </div>
```

And the directive's link function does something like this:

```
const ngmodel = $element.find('[ng-model]').controller('ngModel');
$scope.$watch(()=>ngmodel.$error, addAllClasses, true);
```

Where `addAllClasses` simply makes sure the correct classes appear on the element..

I also tried just adding the same ng-model

```
  <div ng-model="name">
  ...
  </div>
```

But did not see the classes there..

any better way to do this?

Comment: The [tag:angular] tag is for Angular 2+ only, for angular 1.x please use [tag:angularjs]

Comment: @0mpurdy thanks for the comment. I was not aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

This is why we use the angularjs form... I'm really not sure why people are against using a very handy feature.

I've made a plunker for you.
https://plnkr.co/edit/bGOcQjWzlRq2aTYZUYNm?p=preview

```
<form name="form">
    <span ng-class="{red: form.name.$invalid}">Name:</span>
    <input name="name" ng-model="name" required>
</form>
```

A little more insight of what's going on. `form` is added to the scope auto magically by angularjs by it's name. In this case, I named it `form`, however it can be any name.

Now `form` is an ngForm Object and adds all input field into it by their name attributes. This way we can do `form.name` to get another object similar to the ngForm Object. We can then use `$invalid` or `$valid` properties with ng-class.

ngForm is pretty powerful and is loaded with many cool properties and methods. Just call `console.log(scope.form);` You will need to put in a method and add it to ng-change to see updates.

Comment: My directive is unaware if it is in any form. Certainly no idea what is the name of the form. Plus, would like to use outside of form too. Any way to solve it?